# Read pivot data from a sheet

Tags: google-sheets-api

I would like to read pivot table with the google spreadsheet API with the python client to reproduce the pivot table on another sheet.

I saw this in the documentation https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/pivot-tables#read_pivot_table_data but I don't know how to access to this API.

Comment: If you want to retrieve the values from the endpoint of `GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId?fields=sheets(properties.sheetId,data.rowData.values.pivotTable)`, you can achieve this with the method of [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) of Sheets API. About `how to access to this API`, what module will you use for accessing? Do you use [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)? Or do you want to use `request` without using google-api-python-client?

Comment: I use google-api-python-client. But I don't see how to use `GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId?fields=sheets(properties.sheetId,data.rowData.values.pivotTable)` with `result = service.spreadsheets().get(
    ...:             spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ????? 
    ...:             ).execute()`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have how to GET as an example in Python using the [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) library on the [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) reference for Google Sheets:

```
"""
BEFORE RUNNING:
---------------
1. If not already done, enable the Google Sheets API
   and check the quota for your project at
   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets
2. Install the Python client library for Google APIs by running
   `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`
"""
from pprint import pprint

from googleapiclient import discovery

# TODO: Change placeholder below to generate authentication credentials. See
# https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample
#
# Authorize using one of the following scopes:
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
#     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
credentials = None

service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

# The spreadsheet to request.
spreadsheet_id = 'my-spreadsheet-id'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# The ranges to retrieve from the spreadsheet.
ranges = []  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# True if grid data should be returned.
# This parameter is ignored if a field mask was set in the request.
include_grid_data = False  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

request = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, ranges=ranges, includeGridData=include_grid_data)
response = request.execute()

# TODO: Change code below to process the `response` dict:
pprint(response)
```

Comment: I use this example but I don't see how to copy/paste the pivot information. My idea is to use a spreadsheets as a template and generate other spreadsheets.

Comment: You can copy the sheet with copyTo > https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo